# Save and store data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am coding an IOS app in Swift which is a quiz game, at the end of the game you get a score and what I want to do is to save that score to get a highscore. The thing is that I would like to use GameCenter so each player could access to their max score and also to compare the results with the rest of players. Maybe there are other options than GameCenter. I have never done this before so I would like to have some recommendations or advices to take care about.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many tutorials [out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+gamecenter+in+swift&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS770US770&oq=how+to+use+gamecenter+in+swift&aqs=chrome..69i57.6416j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that you can use.